# HttpURLConnection error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out

Tags: java, android

I am using simple urlconnection like this:

```
       url = URL+"getClient&uid="+cl_id;
        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        Log.d("Set++","get_t URL: "+ url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

its working fine, but sometimes i get this error:

```
       error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
```

what could be the reason? I have only 4 clients... so i dont think that the server is overloaded with connections.

the code:

```
    try {
        URL = Settings.BASE_URL + "_interface.php?" +
                "key=" + Settings.KEY +"&app_naam="+Settings.APP_NAAM+ "&action=check&setTime="+c;
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        if(D)Log.e("ChekTreadAanvr+url", URL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String response;
        if ((response = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            rd.close();
        }
        if(D) Log.d("WebSaveThread+","DATARESIEVED:  "+response);
        return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        if(D)Log.d("ERR","server chekc failure ++ ");
        return success = false;
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        if(D)Log.e("ERR", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        success = false;
    }
    return Boolean.toString(success);
```

Comment: Does the URL timeout when you request it from your web browser?

Comment: never got timeout from browser

Comment: confused with your code, please update full code. in you updated code I can not see HttpUrlConnection line.

Comment: shoet.. one moment.. wrong paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be possible that your Internet Connection Speed is weak. You can increase your Timeout Interval by using following method.

```
httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout( 6 * 10 * 1000 ); // One Minute
```

Comment: already tried this one... but same result. some times the error pops out. now i have 1 router between server and telephone. so the weak connection should not be the reason..

Comment: can you tell me the value of your url variable ?

Comment: this is one of the calls"

        http://192.168.15.103/_interface.php?key=drAp9UCU4uD&action=helloServer

Comment: so you are using WiFi in your device or what ?

Comment: yes, telephone is on wifi and server also. Its on VirtualBox on my pc

Comment: ok and how frequently you are getting this problem ? I think it might be after every 6 or 7 execution, is it true ?

Comment: yes, actually I was getting same problem. now please paste your full code in question. I will want to see it.

Comment: by the way.. now i noticed that when i get this error on android cant get on the server webpage..:"Web page is not available"

Comment: well only you need to close your "conn" variable each time before return. so if you upload your full code the i will properly clean your code for you.

Comment: your "conn" variable is not getting close manually so there will be creating many connections ,they's why you are getting this socketException Error, I was getting same. Now I applied httpConnection.close() after all the operations and now it is working very fine.

Comment: hhmmm java developer mostly not think about clearing object after using it. by the way you can chat with me live here any time http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/  , you need 20 reputation for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to a particularly slow server, there are two timeouts that you can set: [`setConnectTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)) and [`setReadTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)).  The names are fairly self explanatory.  For example:

```
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60*1000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60*1000);
```