# How to find what cause java.net.SocketTimeoutException so often with my Android app?

Tags: android, sockets, delphi, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I have a problem and I don't know how to get rid of it. **Sometimes** (that's the main problem, it's just sometimes) I have this exception :

```
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:116)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:150)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:97)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:202)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:119)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:798)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:349)
07-23 01:18:14.198: W/System.err(31750):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderFieldKey(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:174)
```

I know what is basically a socketTimeoutException, but here the problem is that it **can't happen** (or at least not so much) as the server is local and connected to the same router where the phone is connected (I tried with a different router, same problem). And off course the server is working perfectly (When i have an error in the app the log on the server show that the server never receive any request). So what can make that I have sometimes (2 - 10 times per day) a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` that I can't reproduce (just trying again the exact same request and it's work fine).

I m using **delphi** TNetHttpClient (don't know if it's matter) that internally use `HttpURLConnection`

Also what can I do to debug this error to find what is the real reason of the `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` ?

Comment: https://airbrake.io/blog/java-exception-handling/sockettimeoutexception check this , if this helps

Comment: @AnjaniMittal thanks unfortunatly this article is too much generic to socket it's didn't help :( I don't use socket directly, just by httpUrlConnection, my problem is to understand what cause the socket timeout because is surely in the software not in hardware/network

Comment: Is this happening on one particular device, or more than one?

Comment: Also, you might like to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094227/httpurlconnection-error-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out. They talk about a "close" method, but I can't seem to find any. Changing the read timeout perhaps might help?

Comment: @DaveNottage: it's happening in several device, but only for my delphi android app. i never had such error in any other app that i used

Comment: @DaveNottage: hmmm very interesting, if it this that seam that is a bug in the TnetHttpClient, but i need to investigate. not sure it's this need to investigate

Comment: @DaveNottage: not sure it's close, and even it's not very good to close the connection that is keep alive. i m framework i use (and reuse) always the same nethttpclient